# Pythonic approach to pull and group list items based on a list of indices with tuples and non-tuples

Tags: python, list

Consider a list of things. In my actual problem, the things are `matplotlib` artists, but for a more generalized case, lets call the list, `list_of_things`:

```py
list_of_things = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
```

Additionally, we have a list of indices into `list_of_things` in which list elements may or may not be grouped into tuples. Let's call this `list_of_indices`:

```py
list_of_indices = [(3, 1), (2, 0), 4]
```

The desired result is a new list containing items from `list_of_things` which preserves the order and shape of items in `list_of_indices`, like this:

```py
desired_result = [("four", "two"), ("three", "one"), "five"]
```

One approach to solve this is through a loop, using an empty list as a collector of the results:

```py
results = []
for item in list_of_indices:
    if isinstance(item, tuple):
        results.append(
            (list_of_things[item[0]], 
             list_of_things[item[1]])
        )
    else:
        results.append(list_of_things[item])
print(results)
>>> [('four', 'two'), ('three', 'one'), 'five']
```

But this feels obtuse. It seems like there should be a more pythonic, optimized way to do the same thing.

For the curious, what I am after is the ability to group `matplotlib` artist handles (i.e., things plotted in a `pyplot.axes`) together so that I can combine legend items using the [`matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple) method. This comes in handy for cases where for example you are plotting a regression and associated confidence intervals, and only want to show one legend entry. Tupled handles are plotted together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`operator.itemgetter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) would be a good choice (to fetch values by  arbitrary indices):

```
from operator import itemgetter

res = [itemgetter(*(el if isinstance(el, tuple) else [el]))(list_of_things)
       for el in list_of_indices]
```

---

```
[('four', 'two'), ('three', 'one'), 'five']
```

Comment: This is an excellent approach, because is is more generic than my attempt, and can handle the case where a returned tuple has an arbitrary number of elements. I had not used/heard of `operator.itemgetter` before.

Answer (score 0):

We can create map method for each of the types we find in the list of the indices. Since we have only two types, these are enough:

```
def map_int(lst, i):
    return lst[i]

def map_tuple(lst, tpl):
    return tuple(lst[t] for t in tpl)
```

Then, we should have a factory method that calls the right mapper: (Notice I used pattern matching, you can also use simple ifs)

```
def map_all(lst, tpl_or_int):
    match tpl_or_int:
        case int(i):
            return map_int(lst, i)
        case tuple(tpl):
            return map_tuple(lst, tpl)
```

And finally, we can use our factory method to map all our indices.

```
list_of_things = ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
list_of_indices = [(3, 1), (2, 0), 4]

result = list(map(lambda i: map_all(list_of_things, i), list_of_indices))
```

Comment: This was where I was thinking the answer may go. I knew that I could probably create a factory method to use with `map` to get the answer. However, it seems there would be some simpler way to do this that didn't require definition of a factory function(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `numpy` to do that:

```
>>> [np.array(list_of_things)[(i,)].tolist() for i in list_of_indices]

[['four', 'two'], ['three', 'one'], 'five']
```

Obviously if `list_of_things` is already a numpy array, you don't need to cast as array:

```
list_of_things = np.array(list_of_things)
out = [list_of_things[(i,)].tolist() for i in list_of_indices]
```

Comment: I like the use of numpy here, but would prefer to try and keep the solution pure python. Also the returned solution is a multiple list rather than a list with tuples.