# Sorting separate lists of lists by the order of the first one

Tags: python, sorting

I have three lists of lists:

```
days = [[5,2,7],[5,2]]
km = [[2,3,4],[4,3]]
time = [[30,10,20],[15,25]]
```

I would like sort lists in `km` and `time` according to the corresponding list in `day`. So the expected output would be:

```
days = [[2,5,7],[2,5]]
km = [[3,2,4],[3,4]]
time = [[10,30,20],[25,15]]
```

I can sort list of lists using `list(map(sorted, days))` but running the command for each list of lists separately will not work.
I have around 10 lists in total, first one should 'dictate' the order, the rest should be sorted according to it. How can I achieve that using Python?

Answer (score 1):

For just three:

```
days = [[5,2,7],[5,2]]
km = [[2,3,4],[4,3]]
time = [[30,10,20],[15,25]]

for d, k, t in zip(days, km, time):
    d[:], k[:], t[:] = zip(*sorted(zip(d, k, t)))
```

For more:

```
days = [[5,2,7],[5,2]]
km = [[2,3,4],[4,3]]
time = [[30,10,20],[15,25]]
xsss = days, km, time

for xss in zip(*xsss):
    for xs, xs[:] in zip(xss, zip(*sorted(zip(*xss)))):
        pass
```

An `itemgetter` solution:

```
from operator import itemgetter as ig

days = [[5,2,7],[5,2]]
km = [[2,3,4],[4,3]]
time = [[30,10,20],[15,25]]

for lists in zip(days, km, time):
    ordered = ig(*map(ig(0), sorted(enumerate(lists[0]), key=ig(1))))
    for lst in lists:
        lst[:] = ordered(lst)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##rVJNa8QgEL37KzzGZQ752KVlYX9JyCGgm0rWKGqh6Z9Pn8ZtKYWyhxWi8t7Mc95k3Brf7NK9Or9tclwDv/C@P1FLLwOlcxjYbDLYUkdHgEfqAEZtVIa7mpqa2hpMg/gTOHa1nkviM/HI9cI/tauSNhADCJnizDiW7M8DwLxH7BBMsYdgfVSyynm7jBCCMef1ErOSKPfZ3G9ZlTH2LA8fISSd32XvzkDdXR1SWDGzU4QvOSkB4OmPp5QFQyUvLTeG8Ji/q7eGW6f8GPGeNg6yXEdlJhWj8nxEbdPz2pAN33SI4d8fab1UXkmo6Kk6mNFVOGtBvLhWy7tJJasqa/X1AG5W6wVhTWrFdwdvIY9MDvvpD9B9PMpDFYBHBmLbvgA)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all your lists have same shape, by obtaining sorted indices from list `days` and apply them to all subsequent lists:

```
from operator import itemgetter

days = [[5,2,7],[5,2]]
km = [[2,3,4],[4,3]]
time = [[30,10,20],[15,25]]

def sort_by_ind(arr, ind):
    return [itemgetter(*a)(arr[i]) for i, a in enumerate(ind)]

idx_days = [[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(a), key=itemgetter(1))] for a in days]
days = sort_by_ind(days, idx_days)
km = sort_by_ind(km, idx_days)
time = sort_by_ind(time, idx_days)

print(days)
print(km)
print(time)
```

---

```
[[2, 5, 7], [2, 5]]
[[3, 2, 4], [3, 4]]
[[10, 30, 20], [25, 15]]
```

Comment: @KellyBundy, it's not `getter(arr[i])`, -  if applied it should be as `itemgetter(idx)(arr[i])` and it does not (look) shorter than `arr[i][idx]`

Comment: That's only because you're apparently thinking of itemgetter only for extracting a single index instead of **all**, eliminating the list comprehension. Anyway, added it to my answer instead.

Comment: @KellyBundy, " you're apparently thinking of itemgetter only for extracting a single index" - you are wrong, I knew it can be used for multiple indices. And added to answer to show the OP that he has a wider options/alternatives

Comment: @KellyBundy, FYI https://stackoverflow.com/a/75194676/3185459

Comment: Then I don't understand your earlier comments, e.g., why you compared the itemgetter usage to `arr[i][idx]` instead of to `[arr[i][idx] for idx in a]`.

Comment: @KellyBundy, I misread because you start commenting with confused `getter(arr[i])` (and you've deleted those) - that looked vague for me. So see my update with correct application of `itemgetter`

Comment: I really meant `getter(arr[i])`, and it would still be better. Right now you build multiple itemgetters from the same list of indexes. It would be more efficient to build only one and use it multiple times.